# MYSQL Cumulative SUM of QTY

Tags: mysql

I have some problems with this table data, I want get **sum of qty** based on **ItemID**, from **firstdate to current voucherdate** in MySQL

Please help...

TABLE:

```
VCHID  VCHDATE       ITEMID    QTY
-----------------------------------
A1     2019-01-01    Item A    10
A1     2019-01-01    Item B    10
A1     2019-01-01    Item C     5
B2     2019-01-02    Item A     5
B2     2019-01-02    Item B     5
B2     2019-01-02    Item C     5
C3     2019-01-03    Item A    10
C3     2019-01-03    Item B    10
D4     2019-01-04    Item A     5
D4     2019-01-04    Item C     5
D5     2019-01-04    Item A     5
```

Desired result:

```
VCHID  VCHDATE       ITEMID    QTY
-----------------------------------
D4     2019-01-04    Item A    35
D4     2019-01-04    Item C    15
```

Tyvm.

p.s.

I have tested this query :

```
SELECT
    t1.VCHID,
    t1.VCHDATE,
    t1.ITEMID,
    s.QTY
FROM 
    testtable t1
JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         t.ITEMID,
         SUM(t.QTY) AS QTY
     FROM 
         testtable t
     WHERE 
         t.VCHDATE <= '2019-01-04'
     GROUP BY t.ITEMID) s ON t1.ITEMID = s.ITEMID
WHERE 
    t1.VCHID = 'D4';
```

but I have no idea how subquery can automatically read `voucherdate`.

```
(t.VCHDATE <= '2019-04-01')
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and explain why Item B is excluded from the result.

Comment: I just need Item from 'D4'. and get sum of every item on that voucher.

Comment: Cool. As above.

Comment: You don't need to use `DISTINCT` when you have `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join with a query that gets the current voucherdate for each item of D4.

```
SELECT
  t1.VCHID,
  t1.VCHDATE,
  t1.ITEMID,
  s.QTY
FROM testtable t1
  JOIN (SELECT
      t.ITEMID,
      SUM(t.QTY) AS QTY
    FROM testtable t
    JOIN testtable t2 ON t.ITEMID = t2.ITEMID AND t.VCHDATE <= t2.VCHDATE
    WHERE t2.VCHID = 'D4'
    GROUP BY t.ITEMID) s
    ON t1.ITEMID = s.ITEMID
WHERE t1.VCHID = 'D4';
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pLGzZm2zPvsxy5DnaegN4W/0)

Comment: thanks it work. Maybe you have suggestion, how if I want get all voucher from VCHDATE='2019-01-04'. tyvm.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You mean not just `D4`? Change `t2.VCHID = 'D4'` to `t2.VCHDATE = '2019-01-04`

Comment: I just thinking, when I add 't.VCHID = t2.VCHID' on subquery, and change WHERE t1.VCHID = 'D4' to t1.VCHDATE='2019-01-04', it should get new row D5 .. .. 40.